# Changing the format of logging messages coming from Rospy

Tags: ros

I want to change the standard logging output format on ROS1/Noetic running on Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Ideally I would like to have a no-code solution where I can control it via an environment variable or a `.launch` file.

However, nothing seems to work.

- One solution involved installing `rosconsole` so that there would be a python package called `roslog` to import. As far as I can tell the package `rosconsole` does not include such a python package.
- Another solution involved editing this file: `/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros/python_logging.conf` but when I change it and restart Roscoe etc. the effect is not seen.

The change I want is just more concise logging messages (without the long numeric field which I think is a time stamp and a process number, but whatever it is, it is not useful to me right now.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am curious what editorial guidelines you use when you change my questions

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a no code solution that's "good". Other than writing your own logging module specifically for formatting all you can really do is stuff like `roslaunch some_file.launch | grep -ir "some_delim" | awk '{print $2}'`